# MYSQL Finding substring when column contains needle

Tags: mysql, substring

How can I find a string in my database if the database contains the needle?

For example I have the string:
"www.example.com/test"

My database column urlColumn contains:
"www.example.com"

If I do the following (pseudo):

```
SELECT * FROM db WHERE urlColumn LIKE '%www.example.com/test%'
```

I don't get a result. If I change it to (pseudo):

```
SELECT * FROM db WHERE urlColumn LIKE '%www.example.com%'
```

It works. Is it true that the element after LIKE must be the needle and not the haystack? Is it possible to do something like this (pseudo):

```
SELECT * FROM db WHERE %urlColumn% LIKE 'www.exmaple.com/test'
```

Comment: Can you treat the input string as **needle** always ? If so then you can swap their position. And btw, usually :  `Haystack LIKE '%needle%'`

Comment: Do you mean will example.com/test be the needle in all cases? If so, then yes. This string will always have equal or more characters/data than the string in the database.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @1000111.
So this works:
SELECT * FROM db WHERE 'www.exmaple.com' LIKE urlColumn |
But this doesn't .. which I need:
SELECT * FROM db WHERE 'www.exmaple.com/test' LIKE urlColumn |

If I do the following it breaks the query but probably what I need:
SELECT * FROM db WHERE 'www.exmaple.com/test' LIKE %urlColumn%

Comment: Please check the updated query given below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the input string can be treated as `hayStack` then you can use the query given below:

```
SELECT * FROM db WHERE 'www.example.com/test' LIKE CONCAT('%',urlColumn,'%');
```

---

**More:**

There's another way you can determine dynamically that which string should be treated as `HayStack` and which should be treated as `Needle`.

Here's a simple demonstration:

```
SET @hayStack := 'www.example.com';
SET @needle := 'www.example.com/test';

SELECT 

IF(LENGTH(@hayStack) > LENGTH(@needle), 
    @hayStack LIKE CONCAT('%',@needle,'%'),
    @needle LIKE CONCAT('%',@hayStack,'%')
)
```

Comment: Boom. The CONCAT was the key to make this work. Thank you so much!!